# Unable to type #include statements properly in the latest Windows version of Geany IDE

Tags: c++, c, geany

At the time of this writing, the newest version of the Geany IDE is ***1.37.1*** . I came across an issue when using Geany to code in ***C/C++.*** My PC had the following configurations:

***OS:*** Windows 10

***Keyboard Layout:*** EN_US

***Language:*** EN_IN

When I type `#include` followed by a header name such as `<stdio.h>`, the IDE excludes the `.h` extension. I checked if the `Drop rest of word on completion` option is turned on under `Edit->Preferences->Editor->Completions`. I tried including headers using both `<>` and `""`. Also, extensions such as `.txt` also didn't work. Re-installing the IDE didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having the same issue and ***similar keyboard configurations***, I recommend removing any other existing language packs. Typing ***language*** in the search bar brings up a number of options like '''add a language to this device''' and '''Edit language and keyboard options''' etc. Selecting the latter brings up the language section in the Settings app. If you have any other pack installed other than EN_US, select the pack and remove it, ***only if you are sure that you are using a ******US****** keyboard***. Now restart the Geany IDE and try typing `#include` statements once again. The above approach worked for me.